# Cellular automata for 2d cloud simulation

Tags: algorithms, cellular-automata

I want to build a cellular automata that simulates a behaviour that looks like clouds, that is: infinite and random cycles, pieces can gather or break apart, just like the image below:[image]

My question is: **Is there any algorithm whose result looks like this cycle (or anything that can help me)?**

I've been searching for a long time throught articles, scientific papers, epidemic algorithms, Conway's Game of Life similars, but still no result.

Comment: Is there exists any algorithm using computer which produce above pictures? If yes, then there are cellular automata in which equivalent with Turing machine, so by Church Turing thesis you can simulate it using 2d cellular universal cellular automata.

Comment: I've seen it done, but I have no access to the algorithm so I'm searching how to get to its result. These images in the post are only fictional, I drew them just to illustrate